# Помогите найти ошибку в алгоритме

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

> Вместо х и у нужно вписать числа и оно должно решить пример но у меня где-то ошибка

```
x = int(input("Введіть змінну х: "))
y = int(input("Введіть змінну y: "))

import math
b = math.exp(math.sqrt(math.fabs(x-y)) + math.ceil (1 + math.e) * math.log2(math.tan(2))  + (math.sqrt(math.ceil(x))/y**3))
print ("Відповідь: ", b)
```

Comment: Во первых, почему int? Во вторых, почему Math.ceil?

Comment: Ну я не очень опитний, а что должно быть вместо  math.ceil ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Исходя из примера, `sqrt` здесь - лишнее

   `math.exp(math.sqrt(math.fabs(x-y))`
2. Здесь нужен не `ceil()`, а `log()`

   `math.ceil (1 + math.e)`
3. Здесь нужен не `ceil()`, a `fabs()`

   `(math.sqrt(math.ceil(x))/y**3))`
4. Несмотря на вышеперечисленное, ошибка кроется не в вашем коде, а в самом примере :

   `tg(2) < 0` ==> `log2(tg(2))` - не определен на числовой прямой, или просто не существует.
   Чтобы все таки решить пример, попробуйте брать тангенс не от 2 радиан, а от 2 градусов, в таком случае ответ должен получиться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ